# Download File by Name from Document Library Programatically

Tags: sharepoint-server, development

Using SharePoint Server object model how can you retrieve a specific document by name in a Document Library, so that the file can be downloaded programatically?

I am finding a lot of articles with examples of iterating through a list or document library.  I would like to be able to retrieve a specific file by name, so that I can get the bytes or stream.  Is this possible?

Thanks for any tips or advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SPWeb.GetFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getfile.aspx) method to retreive the document by its name.

Here's the example part of the code which can be used to solve your problem:

```
string s = "http://sp/Library/filename.png";
var f = web.GetFile(s);
if (f.Exists)
{
    var b = f.OpenBinary();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\temp\\fileName.png", b);
}
```

The `web` variable is the `SPWeb` that contains your library. You should create that object yourself or use the one from `SPContext`. You should also change the url of the file to match your file (variable `s` in my example).